# How do I create a new Series from values of an existing pandas Series while retaining original index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a Series of time zones.

s=pd.Series(times_zones)

s

```
0          America/New_York
1            America/Denver
2          America/New_York
3         America/Sao_Paulo
4          America/New_York
               ...         
3435       America/New_York
3436        America/Chicago
3437         America/Denver
3438    America/Los_Angeles
3439       America/New_York
Length: 3440, dtype: object
```

I would like to create a new Series containing all the 'America/New_York' values while retaining the index of their original position in s.

How would one do this?

I tried s1=s.values(['America/New_York']) which returns:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [111], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 s.values(['America/New_York'])

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

I also tried s.loc[] but loc/iloc only work on indexes to my understanding, not on values

I also tried s2 = pd.Series(s.values(['America/New_York'])) to no avail

Please help a pandas/Python newbie :)

Comment: Use `s[s=='America/New_York']`

Comment: You can use iloc with condition.